# custom load more text function

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, toggle

Lets say we have this:

```
<div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p> 

    <p>Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p> 

    <p>Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p> 

    <p>Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>

</div>
<div class="porfolio-single-load-more">
    <a href="#" class="icon-holder prevent-history">
        <i class="icon-plus"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

And we want to show only the first 300 chars and when clicking to the load more button, to show the rest of the text,

I guess the solution is to wrap the exceding chars into a hidden div, but i don't know how to do so,

how can i wrap from the char 301 untill the end of the text with a div?

```
var textcnt = this.mainCnt.find('.single-portfolio .content');
if(textcnt.text().length > 300){
    /* ?? */
}else{
        $('.porfolio-load-more a').remove();
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding CSS to the table..

Its quite tricky not to break the markup (specially when users that will update it haver no HTML knowledge)

So this is what I did:

```
var textcnt = this.mainCnt.find('.single-portfolio .content');
        if(textcnt.text().length > 300){
            /* ?? */
            textcnt.addClass('ellipsis');
            this.mainCnt.on('click','.porfolio-single-load-more a',function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                $('.porfolio-single-load-more a').fadeOut(300,function(){ textcnt.removeClass('ellipsis');$(this).remove(); });
            });
        }else{
            $('.porfolio-single-load-more a').remove();
        }
```

And then with css

```
.ellipsis{ max-height: 300px; /* som amount that matchs the line-height*font-size per line (ex: 5lines*18px*20px) */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var wtext = $('.content').html().substr(300);
$('.content').html( $('.content').html().substr(0, 300) + '<span class="hidden">' + wtext + '</span>' );
```

Of course, this takes no care to tags, so it can unfortunately be splitted in the middle of a html tag. In that case, you need some sort of check to prevent that for happening.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that each line of code is its own DOM element. If you can't refactor the underlying html, what you're going to have to do is iterate over each p element, pull out the HTML text (and append to a string), wipe the content div, then insert the string plus a div divider.

So something like

```
var full = "";
$('.content').children('p').each(function(){
  full = full.concat($(this).html());
}
$('.content').html("");
var first = full.substring(0, 300);
var rest = full.substring(301);
$('.content').append(first + "</div><div id=\"hidden\">" + rest);
```

which will split the div the way you want. Set display of hidden to none, then you attach an onclick handler to your button with $.on() to show() it

Answer (score 0):

Try to use jquery data to store full text. I make a simple test. You could try it.

JavaScript:

```
var $textcnt = $(".content p");
if($textcnt.text().length>300){
    $.data(document.body,"content",$textcnt.text());
    $textcnt.text($textcnt.text().substr(0,300)+"...");
}else
{
   $("#read-more").remove(); 
}

$("#read-more").click(function(){
    $textcnt.text($.data(document.body,"content"));
});
```

Html:

```
<div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    <a id="read-more" href="#" class="icon-holder prevent-history">
        Read more
    </a>
</div>
```

Here is **[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Tk4pQ/1/)**

Hope this is helpful for you.